# What's the difference between transforming data in an angular ngModelController.$formatter and transforming it during ngModelController.$render?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

When should I introduce the complexity of an ngModelController.$formatter when transforming data for a view?

In other words, in the following (contrived) examples, is capitalizerA better than capitalizerB? 'A' feels more idiomatic, but I'm having trouble finding a distinct advantage.

```
var app = angular.module('capitalizerApp', [])

app.controller('capitalizerCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'jake';
});

/*
*  capitalizerA
*/
app.directive('capitalizerA', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      let _capitalizerFormatter = function(value) {
        return value.toUpperCase();
      }

      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(_capitalizerFormatter);

      ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
        scope.capsName = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
      }
    }
  }
});

/*
*  capitalizerB
*/
app.directive('capitalizerB', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
        scope.capsName = scope.name.toUpperCase();
      }
    }
  }
})
```

See the following working example: http://codepen.io/telekid/pen/oxNxPM?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that you aren't "adding complexity" either way. No matter which function you use, you are bringing in NgModelController. I think the reasons for doing this are few beyond the $validator pipeline. I have found that filters can do many things that one might be tempted to use the $formatters pipeline for.

That said, there are uses, and I think the most appropriate place to put logic is in the $parsers or $formatters arrays.